# How do I import a three.js (JSON from blender) model into Unity at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js, model, blender

I've already managed to get the list of all vertices, normals, and uvs, but I can't generate the mesh correctly.
The JSON file was generated by the blender.

Comment: Hi Vincenzo Fabiano, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you seen the following?

https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/07/27/importing-blender-modelized-mesh-in-threejs.html

Does this answer the question and, if not, what further might you be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to import your JSON model into the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) editor and then export to `glTF` or `Collada`. These formats should be easier to import into Unity.

Apart from that, you should not use the JSON Blender exporter anymore. It was removed from the project several releases ago. The recommended 3D format is glTF. More information about that topic right here:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models